# Vim: Map Cmd-Alt-j to tabprevious?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, macvim

I'm having a heck-of-a time with this.  I've started using tabs more in MacVim and I'm trying to make a mapping of Cmd+Alt+j and Cmd+Alt+k to move back and forth between tabs.  Similar to using Cmd+Alt+Left or Right in Textmate, but without having to leave the home row.

When I try the following, it just simply doesn't work:

```
nnoremap <D-M-j> :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <D-M-k> :tabnext<CR>
```

Furthermore, if I try to type the actual keystroke into my gvimrc, I get instead a `<D-M-(delta symbol)>` or a `<D-M-(degree symbol)>` instead.

Is there some secret I'm missing, or something stupid I'm doing?

Comment: Why don't you use gt and gT ?

Comment: @Vulgrin : it should not be `<C-M-j>` for Ctrl+Alt+j ? I am not on OSX so the `D` might be something special ?

Comment: @Xavier: Yep. We have control, option (meta), and command in Macs (C, M and D)

Comment: For that kind of issue you can start by looking at the result of `:verbose map <D-m-j>`. If you see something, it means it is correctly defined. If not it has not been taken into account. Potentially you can also find out that one of your plugin is using the same mapping, and thus disabling yours.

Comment: verbose map lists it as the mapping I've set up.

Comment: @Benoit what do you mean?  I'm a vim noob, so I don't understand.

Comment: Benoit means that the most efficient way to navigate to the next and previous tabs is to type `gt` and `gT` respectively.

Comment: I think that MacVim (and vim) doesn't really support multiple modifiers. If that's the case, `<C-M-j>` is probably interpreted silently as `<C-j>`. I remember trying to mimic a TextMate shortcut when I was starting to learn vim, something like `<C-Shift-Up>` without success. Now, I just think that trying to force vim to be another editor is rather foolish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set macmeta` will make your `<M-D-j>` binding work.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

`nnoremap <D-M-j> gt` To go to the next tab

`nnoremap <D-M-k> gT` To go to the previous tab

you can extend this by using this to switch buffers as well by replace in `gt` and `gT` with `:bn<cr>` and `:bp<cr>` respectively